# Marinating time for St. Louis Ribs

Tags: marinade

Can you marinate St Louis Ribs for 48 hours?  I’m using a Garlic and Soy marinade for Chinese Sticky Ribs. It’s a mostly dry rub (brown sugar, salt, dry mustard, ginger, clove and grainy Dijon mustard) as the only wet ingredient.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're doing it in a refrigerator, you can pretty much marinate as long as the meat would be safe in the fridge while not marinating.

Whether the results suit you, you'll have to test.